# What are those curious properties that I've found in my sqlConnection?

Tags: c#, .net, sqlconnection

Whilst investigating a very dull and exponetially security flawful 2005 project, I debugged into a connection hang.
Inspecting the object, to find the server name, I've encountered this three little properties:

- *`IsShiloh`*
- *`IsKatmaiOrNewer`*
- *`IsYukonOrNewer`*

What are those members and why are they so **awesomely** named?

Comment: Yukon is the old codename for sql server 2005.

Comment: "Katmai" was SQL Server 2008's code-name, "Shiloh" was SQL Server 2000

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe these are all different codenames for different versions of SQL Server.  The [Wikipedia article for SQL Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server#Genesis) lists the different codenames:

```
8.0     2000    SQL Server 2000     Shiloh
9.0     2005    SQL Server 2005     Yukon
10.0    2008    SQL Server 2008     Katmai
```

Also, just for funsies, the codenames [follow a National Park naming pattern](http://dbfriend.blogspot.com/2010/10/code-names-for-sql-server.html).